# Cover letter vs CV vs research statement at academicjobsonline

Tags: application, application-cover-letter, research-statement

I'm applying for postdoc positions via [academicjobsonline](https://academicjobsonline.org/ajo) and a typical call requires (1) Cover letter (2) CV (3) Research statement. Previously I was applying to an [aggregate](https://itf.fys.kuleuven.be/postdoc-application/) of European universities and this application form only required СV and research statement. My CV is a precise chronological summary of my academic history while the research statement describes my past and current interests and plans. What should I write in the cover letter then? I'm new to this application business and not sure what is the distinction between all these types of letters.

Comment: http://theprofessorisin.com/2016/08/26/why-your-job-cover-letter-sucks/ The book is probably in your library.